# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to get the last row in the table but throwing error ...

> 'Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, string given in '

```
$recents = "SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
if ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recents)) {
    $mName = $result['name'];
    $mDesc = $result['description'];
    $mCost = $result['cost'];
}
```

Comment: your query does not return any record, check you db connection and echo your query.

Comment: You need to execute your query before you try to get rows from the result.

Comment: where is `mysqli_query()` ???

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass a result from a query, not the query string.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$recent = mysqli_query($connetion, $sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use the statement to run the query

```
$results=mysqli_query($conn,$recents)
```